# Variable no almacena valor de una funcion

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de hacer un bot que organice mi horario de clases, para ello use la libreria SheetJS, ya pude extraer los datos y mostrarlos en consola, pero lo que no puedo hacer es guardarlos en una variable, especificamente la variable horario, al momento de querer mostrarlos en consola aparace que es undefined, y hasta unos pocos segundos despues carga el consol.log de la varible a. El texto concatenado es nada mas para ver cual se esta disparando

```
<html>
<head>
<script lang="javascript" src="recursos/js/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
var url = "horario.xlsx";

/* set up async GET request */
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", url, true);
req.responseType = "arraybuffer";

req.onload = function(e) {
  var data = new Uint8Array(req.response);
  var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type:"array"});
  var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
  var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
  let a = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json( worksheet );
  
  console.log (a + "a");
  return a

}

 let horario ;
 
 
 horario = req.send();

 

 console.log (horario + "o");



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No te va a devolver nada, en si tienes que usar el atributo onreadystatechange, este se llama siempre que cambia:

```
req.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
  if (req.readyState == 4) {
     if(req.status == 200)
      let horario=req.responseText;
     else
      console.log("Error loading page\n");
  }
};
```